# ActiveAdmin set permit_params on renamed resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I renamed a resource in Active Admin like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Member, :as =>  "AllMember" do

...

end
```

When I want to save the form through Active Admin every field will become empty before validation. So I get an error that all fields are blank, and I should fill the fields. 
In the log file I get this message:

```
Processing by Admin::AllMembersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pvvMTKT8vLDDv+fm9aWPyFGTRtwFAsuCEHYn4mXjT9A=", "all_member"=>{"pre_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"ghk"}, "commit"=>"something"}

Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, all_member, commit
```

How is it possible that all of the parameters are unpermitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3149

Based on this issue, you have to update your ActiveAdmin gem. ;)